# How to decorate a line with arrows and circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like to draw an arrow (ray of light) overlayed with perpendicular double headed arrows and circles (to show both s & p polarisation), but I am struggling with decoration commands. I have included what I have so far, can you help me get further?

What I currently have:

[image: What I currently have]

(Nasty mockup of) what I would like:

[image: what I would like]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

    \draw [red, line width=1mm, <-]  (0,0) -- (150:5.2)
        [postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.9 step 0.2 with {\arrow[red, line width=1mm]{|};}
        }}]
        [postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=between positions 0.3 and 0.9 step 0.2 with {\circle{8};}
        }}]
        ;       

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The markings have a local coordinate system with x direction along the tangent and y direction along the normal so you can draw things using that coord system.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \draw [red, line width=1mm, <-, 
        postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.9 step 0.2 with {\draw [<->,red,thin] (0,-2mm) -- (0,2mm);}
        }}
        ,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=between positions 0.3 and 0.9 step 0.2 with {\draw[thin,blue] circle (3pt);}
        }}]
         (0,0) -- (150:5.2);       

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]